# How does C evaluate 2 minuses with 2 operands?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Consider:

```
    int a;
    a = -3--3;
    printf("%d", a);
```

The 2nd line `(a = -3--3)` produces a compile time error.
On adding an extra pair of brackets as follows:

```
    int a;
    a = -3 - (-3);
    printf("%d", a);
```

the error disappears.

Since the brackets remove the error I believe that some ambiguity must have caused it.

But I don't see why the compiler is confused. I try to subtract `-3` from `-3`.

---

All help is appreciated.

Comment: won't it be recognized as `(-3)--` followed by `-3` which would cause a syntax error much like `5--1` ?

Comment: Why this urge to subtract two negative numbers? `-3+3` would work, and so would `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C has a unary decrement operator that's spelled `--`, and a "maximal munch rule" that makes it recognize that operator rather than a minus sign and a negative sign even where the latter would make more sense. For about half a dozen accompanying reasons, `3 -- 3` doesn't make sense, and you get an error.

If you'd said `a = -3 - -3;`, instead of cramming everything together like your space bar's broken, you'd have been fine. :P A space between the two operators keeps C from seeing a `--`.

Comment: But since `--` is a unary operator shouldn't C be designed to not read it as one between two operands?
And is placing `--` above `-` an flaw in C? It could've avoided arguments like this one? And Thanks for the answer +1

Comment: @SmarthBansal, the tokenization of the input sequence happens in a very early stage of processing where nothing is known about about the context.

Comment: @SmarthBansal That is exactly where the "maximum munch" rule kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

Taking for granted that you know that "--" represents a unary operator for pre/post decrement, it is easy to understand the reason why the compilers throw an error.

The parser of the C compiler reads the first minus sign, then, it expects either a number (meaning that your intention is to perform a regular substraction) or another minus sign (meaning that your intention is to perform a pre-decrement unary operation. In your case, you are basically telling the C compiler that you want to perform a pre-decrement. It doesn't make sense for two reasons:

a) If your intention was actually to perform a pre-decrement operation, then you are missing an extra binary operator (e.g. "+"), just like this: a = -3 + (--3).

b) The other reason (which makes my previous example also to throw a compile time error, is that you are trying to perform a unary operation on a constant. Totally non-sense, since the compiler reserves memory for a constant that you are, later on, trying to modify.

Hope this helps to get the concept of expressions in "C", a source of many headaches for beginners (and even for experts sometimes!).

My advice: keep the code clean, meaningful and use braces as much as common sense tells, which is the contrary that you did, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!